# Build latex document without references section

Tags: bibliographies

I want to do the plagiarism check of my article written in latex. How can I build the article without the references section.

I am using
\begin{thebibliography}
\item{}
\end{thebibliography}
to build references.

Comment: just delete the section and put it back later? you are building the list by hand not using bibtex or  biber?

Comment: Alternative: Use a program like `pdfjam` or `pdftk` to split the PDF.

Comment: pdfjam is a good option.